# html5 svg vs canvas for granite like background

Tags: html, html5-canvas

i want to make to make a granite like background like http://www.tivli.com/ with a gradient at the center. i have found how to do gradient with both in the w3c tutorials, but are there any tutorials on how to make granite backgrounds in html5 canvas or svg? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a simple filter could do the trick.

Comment: yes you are right. feel free to post the details or ill probably do it later.

Comment: i have only tried to make it kind of pixelated, its close but not the same effect. right?

Comment: I'm not sure atm, you could try http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html or perhaps create an imageoverlay with a granite-texture (and low opacity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you referenced actually uses a simple 'noize.png' and then uses css3 radial gradients to buildup that background. I know you already knew that, I'm mentioning this for future readers.
*Given this fact, I'll assume in the rest of my answer you want to learn, not a copy-pasta solution.*

**I've** given up on svg looong time ago. But in canvas it's easy and fun... (especially now flash is FINALLY officially dead. Hurray).

So as others have already suggested in the comments to your question, why not use a **seamless** noise image? (you know where to find one :P).
You could still embed this image as 'DATA' in the html(, HINT: even or even feed image-data straight into canvas that will render it as your 'noise.php').

But then.. you are right: what if you wanted to change the noize-size?
And you want to know how to make granite/noise anyway..
And is mathematically/programmatically describing this noise lower in character-count (file-size) than supplying a ready-made image(-fragment)?

**Start UPDATE 2 part 1:**
Actually, after some good night sleep I realized/remembered that visual noise is one of the BEST way's to determine randomness. Humans are notoriously good at finding visual patterns, even [professionals use this](http://www.random.org/bitmaps/) (and as such this is also heavily used in cryptography where one would need -for instance- a useful [one time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)).
Also see '[commander](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0238380/)' Crockford's YUI-lecture ['Principles of Security' from 19m07s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKuFu19LgZA&t=19m07s) to 22m37s.

Now why is this important? Well [ECMA-script (aka javascript) defines a loose Math.random() function](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf#page=128):

> "returns a number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with
>   *approximately uniform distribution over that range, **using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy***"

Re-read the italic/bold part and welcome yourself to reality: each and every browser (brand/version) has it's own random-routine!!
"But what does it mean?" Well.. simply put.. Depending on browser(version)'s ES-Script implementation (cough cough IE): **Noise based on Math.random() will/might render visible patterns** in your noise (independently of possible tile-size)!!
So for the rest of this answer we are going to assume either an ideal world where browsers spit-out proper random numbers, or that you took control and use a stronger 'predictable' random-solution as is discussed on [this wonderful article](http://web.archive.org/web/20101106000458/http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/) that google's [bubble](http://dontbubble.us/) accidentally leaked :)
**End Update 2 part 1**

So let's start with the radial gradient-part. You already figured that one out.

Ok, then follows the noise-function in canvas (you could you could do this before the radial gradient, but this order gives a nicer grain and diffuses [color banding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_banding) the gradient produces -on a average lcd you would see them anyway since they're not true color-) : ***this is done by generating random pixels***.
There would be a lot of different algorithms to use, I've used a straight-forward one that you can understand without math..
Note that generating noise for a modern day full-screen resolution is easily larger than 1 mega-pixel in resolution, so this would be slow! To overcome this we need to generate and RE-USE a small seamless tile. We use this as a *pattern-fill* in our full-size image that already has the radial gradient.

I also assume you want the radial gradient liquidly placed in the middle of the view-port, so if you want to go the fixed way (as opposed to the noize.png/css3 way you referenced), you'll also need an extra eventhandler 'onResize()' to have canvas render a new background.
Why? Well if you where to let the browser scale this background-image (created upon page-load) automatically, then the nice grain-size of your noise would change to, EVEN leading to visible PATTERNS that you would not want..

(Since I desperately want to go to sleep now..): The rest is thoroughly explained in the source-code of the function I wrote for you..

**Here is the link to the fully documented code I wrote for you:** [jsfiddle.net/sU74C/](http://jsfiddle.net/sU74C/) and here you can see it in [full-screen preview](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sU74C/show/).   **UPDATE 1:** function genNoise 80% FASTER!!

Use it if you like (retaining the link to this answer) or learn from it and do your own thing.
PLEASE DON'T FORGET to accept AN answer to this question (hopefully mine :))

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE 2 part 2:**
There are more way's to interact with canvas. One could also calculate/(re-)use/generate/save/import pixel-maps/array's (as png or base64 or jpg or ...) for instance, see this [excellent article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/) on faster 8bit and even faster 32bit (if the browser supports 'Uint8ClampedArray' as the type of the data property of the ImageData object) pixel-array's, including a proper solution to account for the endianness of the processor!!

So after giving this some considerable thought, it turns out that to do this 'right' is actually a challenge and should be divided in 2 parts:

- Where do I get my noise-data (Math.random() or custom random or pre-defined external (image, json-string, random.com) or embedded (packed?) data)?
- What is the fastest way to build/store/re-use this noise on full-screen size/canvas.

Given the statements in part 1 of this update and that we don't want patterns in our visible noise, I'm starting to lean to using some pre-rendered 'random' noise data (meant to tile seamlessly) that is embedded in the noise-generator: otherwise there is the overhead of running your own none-engine-optimized random function (times..a lot..).
Also I think one might get away with just black and white and transparency afterwards.. This might considerably speed-up things up AND reduce embedded pixel-data.
Think about it: black or white equals 0 or 1..
In base 64 one character can represent 6 bits. So a 30x30px image has 900 px divided by 6 bits = 150 characters (sweet-spot increments by 6px, so next is 36px*36px is 216 characters).

Comment: thank you so much dude. would you mind sharing references to graphics tutorials?

Comment: You are welcome. And thank you for accepting. Since I'm actually still on this subject privately, I'll update some key-issues to this current answer. What 'references to graphics tutorials' are you talking about? The above is my own work, relevant links are included.