# Does using canvas result in a smaller HTTP request than using an image

Tags: javascript, html, http

I know converting any image format to SVG is not an easy task, and it is not something I am pursueing for complex images. Let me explain why I am asking this question. As a web designer, there are elements in a site that I will commonly use an image for. There include simple geometric shapes, fleur-de-lis, some simple logos etc. The cost of these HTTP requests is relatively small (we are talking KB's here).

However, I am interested if these requests could be even smaller by using svg or other canvas elements instead of an image format for simple images. Has there been any research or testing to compare SVG vs. an image? Is it possible that I can make HTTP requests even smaller by using canvas for simple elements on my page? If so it would be great news. I could even start creating libraries of canvas images to re-use and share with others.

Comment: canvas is only available in more modern browsers and is not compatible with IE version 8 and below and older versions of firefox. Since IE8 is the terminal version of XP, you may want to maintain support for it.

Comment: @bizzehdee that is the case sometimes, but in other websites, the client wants a rich HTML5 web experience and isn't interested in maintaining older browser support, due to the cost involved (my html5 is becoming the new flash!)

Comment: 'older versions of firefox'..  The last decent firefox branch 3.6x (you know.. the engine the current web was built upon) supports canvas quite nicely (speaking from own experience)!!! Maybe even older.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will depend on the case.

Sprites can help.. but what if your sprite contains some simple lines yet must be 500px * 500px... then a canvas (or even svg) will indeed be a lot smaller.  On top of that, external javascripts usually are cached (even better than images). In that regard, they indeed help slim down the weight.

However, if you'd expect IE to also 'work', then you might need to start to provide some html5/canvas shims and yes that would increase the weight.

**Edit:**
Look at this [jsfiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sU74C/show/) (I whipped up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466587/html5-svg-vs-canvas-for-granite-like-background)) where a full-size 'granite' background is created with a radial gradient.
As you can see (in the source) this is a LOT less bytes then a separate image (and will alway's be pixel-perfect).

On the other hand, it also (depending on the complexity) take some calculation-time that regular images wouldn't take (after the necessary bytes are downloaded to the client).

**Edit2:**
I found a [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/16/resolution-independence-with-svg/) where they did a little test.

> In our sprite example, the raw SVG file was 2445 bytes. The PNG
>   version was only 1064 bytes, and the double-sized PNG for double-pixel
>   ratio devices was 1932 bytes. On first appearance, the vector file
>   loses on all accounts, but for larger images, the raster version more
>   quickly escalates in size.
>
> SVG files are also human-readable due to being in XML format. They
>   generally comprise a very limited range of characters, which means
>   they can be heavily Gzip-compressed when sent over HTTP. This means
>   that the actual download size is many times smaller than the raw file
>   — easily beyond 30%, probably a lot more. Raster image formats such as
>   PNG and JPG are already compressed to their fullest extent.

However, note all this is *still* depending how complex the image is: as an extreme counter-example.. try to describe a full color photo of a forrest (leaves..) versus simply a jpg..

Comment: Why wouldn't SVG always be smaller than a sprite? Won't transmiting javascript be cheaper?

Comment: It really depends. You could also use javascript to create the svg for instance (but I don't like that, I really like canvas -the new flash- better). Say for exampe, you need some icon-like buttons.. with gradients and a lot of lines, detail and artwork. I'll bet you that a gif/png will be smaller than describing all detailed (almost) single pixels!   Also, sprites (for use as buttons) actually make things look web2.0  without a need for javascipt-preloaders and onmouse-events (saving again code = bytes)!!!  However, and this is a big BUT.. describing images (svg/canvas) will let you scale..!

Comment: ok, I'm not following how svg/canvas will let you scale though

Comment: because you can mathematically describe the image like a vector. Look at the code of that js-fiddle for example (also resize your window!!!). Extra explanation: in that example where there is 'noise', you could not scale that without hurting the noise if it was a fixed size image.. Another example: say you want to draw fullsize (but liquid working) 'window'/'boxes'.. you could call your function that drives the canvas to render the image (not scale it) to a specific size. Have a fixed round corner-radius of x diameter but stretch the straight lines and apply a gradient in percent..

Answer (score 1):

For simple shapes gzipped SVG will be pretty small and in modern browsers it's [quite usable](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

However, for page loading performance number of requests is a very big factor, so you'll get significant performance boost if you use [CSS sprite sheets](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) regardless of the image format.

If by canvas you mean storing shapes as JavaScript drawing commands (or a library that issues them based on some JSON) then it's unlikely to be big bandwidth saving compared to gzipped SVG (SVG has quite efficient format for defining paths, and gzip removes overhead of XML quite well).

You will have to wait for JS to load and either insert several canvases all over the document or burn CPU on compressing generated images and building `data:` URLs, so I don't think it'd be faster overall than using SVG or [optimized PNG](http://pngmini.com).

Comment: The javscript could be minified which could result in it being smaller than the GZIPPED compressed SVG.

Comment: I'm assuming minified already. The biggest source of entropy are going to be storage of paths anyway, e.g.: `var d=['M',1,2,'L',3,4]` vs `<path d="M1 2 L3 4"/>` — and there's hardly anything you can do more than SVG does already, plus whatever compression you come up with, you'll have to send and execute decoding code too. And raw `beginPath()` minified JS is going to be pretty fat too.

Comment: you make a convicing case. What if the javascript though is re-usable? Say I have multiple circle in different colors and sizes.

Comment: @stevebot gzip compresses using backreferences "this bit is same as that bit X bytes ago", so that can be as effective as simple function calls. You could have advantage in JS if you used algorithmically-generated geometry (e.g. fractals or pseudorandom shapes).

Answer (score 0):

The size always depends on the specific images, sorry but you have to test it at your own. There is no way to compare this in general.

Comment: If I tested this *generally* it would give me an idea of what the comparison is in *general*. I am asking if anybody has already done testing or can reason a case.